# What happens when an npm package is deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I was reading an article on how the author of a popular npm package (left-pad) caused apps to break after he deleted his package.

How could this be the case?  Isn't an npm package's code locally downloaded when you `npm install --save`? The only case where I'd imagine this being a problem would be for those who were using the project via CDN.  Are my assumptions correct?

src article: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/

Comment: When you do npm install {anything} it downloads the package into your node_modules folder locally and will continue to run. The --save option ensures that your package.json file reflects the exact version you used in your project. This is relevant when someone installs your module, they'll get the same version instead of the latest. If the package is deleted and yours depends on it, that would then cause an issue when someone tries to install your package from scratch (because they'll need to download the now deleted package)

Comment: Yes, but continuous integration suites usually re-download everything to make sure they have a clean slate to to tests with.  Those tests and fresh deploys instantly broke.

Comment: Why would it be an issue if the source code is installed locally in the node_modules folder?

Comment: @lightspeed because during build process you generally `npm install`. Well, think about it. It will try to download the deleted package and fail because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Does that mean every build process requires a network connection?  I do recall doing builds offline?

Comment: If the packages are not locally cached somehow, yes. *"I do recall doing builds offline?"* npm caches packages. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Comment: @lightspeed how else would you download packages?

Comment: @lightspeed test it out. Kill your network connection and try to npm install something

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I understand that you need a network connection and the package needs to be available when you first install it.  What I'm trying to understand is why applications that already had the npm package installed failed when that package was deleted?  It's not like you continuously do `npm install`.

Comment: @lightspeed Everytime you deploy an app to production, `npm install` will be ran. Check Nik's answer, it should be accepted.

Comment: *"It's not like you continuously do npm install"* That's exactly what happens in CI environments. And even if you didn't, this is a transitive problem. A missing npm package effects any package that has a dependency on it. And there is always someone that installs a package for the first time.

Comment: @lightspeed if you are running an app locally, sure you arent going to keep running npm install. However, node_modules isnt meant to be kept in source control because it is generated from running `npm install`. A typical automated flow would be `check code into git (without node_modules)` -> `download source code on host machine` -> `run npm install` -> `start app`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Makes sense.  Is this the process every time you build?  I can imagine updates to a project that don't modify dependencies.

Comment: @lightspeed in an automated deployment, yes, but I mean you could always ssh into the machine and manually update and start the app. But the whole point of a CI/CD environment is that you can push code to source control and have the build/deployment process automated. All you should have to do is `git push`. Nik Kyriakides stated it beautifully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Most projects don't commit the actual modules to source control

The `node_modules` folder is usually not uploaded on source control such as Git or SVN. It's quite often a humongous folder and it would be cumbersome to push/pull it each time.

Plus some modules contain C++ code and are compiled upon installation to the user's OS. I might have a different OS than the user that installed it, hence that module wouldn't work if I blindly downloaded his own compiled version of that module from source control.

Instead a small config. file such as `package.json` is included which *describes* which modules are required for the project. When you run `$ npm install`, the package manager ([npm](https://github.com/npm/npm) or [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn)) then reads that file and starts downloading the modules it references.

Each time the project gets deployed or cloned, the machine downloads the source code from it's repository but *without the modules* (since they're not on source control) and then a human or a machine runs `$ npm install` to also get the dependent/required modules.

### Projects get deployed and built all the time

Now, projects get deployed on remote servers **all the time**; i.e deploying the project to a production server or it's tests run on a remote [CI server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) or even cloned by other developers on their local machines. Projects I work on get deployed & tested on a remote CI server at the very least 5 times a day; every time we push a commit to the remote repository.

Since that user deleted his much dependent-on module, a lot of `$ npm install`s around the globe started to fail. A lot of people couldn't push updates to projects on their production server, other developers couldn't get the project on their machine so they can work on it etc...

As a safeguard against these issues, [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) introduced [a policy](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish) that prohibits un-publishing modules that are more than 72h old:

From [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/):

> Registry data is immutable, meaning once published, a package cannot change. We do this for reasons of security and stability of the users who depend on those packages. So if you've ever published a package called "bob" at version 1.1.0, no other package can ever be published with that name at that version. This is true even if that package is unpublished. However, because accidents happen we've allowed a 72 hour window for users to unpublish packages they have just created.

Comment: Makes sense.  Does a fresh `npm install` happen every time you build?  I can imagine updates to a project that don't modify dependencies.

Comment: That I don't know for sure so I can't answer myself. All I know is that if I (or my deployment/CI server) run `$ npm install` the installed modules align with what `package.json` describes.

Comment: Under some circumstances, it is also possible to unpublish versions [older than 72h](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish#packages-published-more-than-72-hours-ago), so this safeguard will not always protect you.

Comment: This is amazing, I was struggling here to find a solution like jfrog or nexus to have my own repository storing the libs our team is using. With that safeguard from npm, I'm not sure If I would still use those tools